# Arduino stk500_getsync(): not in sync

Tags: serial, arduino-pro-mini, accelerometer

We have an arduino pro mini, we are trying to trying to upload sketch the controller but we are prohibited, as the arduino attempt to upload the sketch, it display an error of: not in sync.

We are pretty new in this are, so any help would be much appreciated.

Our setup is: -Breadboard -Connection to adapter: USB Serial. -Arduino Pro Mini as a controller

Through the Arduino Programming Client.

The processor and the port are setup op properly.

The strange thing is, it has worked sometimes these past days..

Much Thanks.

Mieer

Comment: Try pressing the reset button just before uploading, might be that the reset signal isn't sent right as it's going through the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is intermittent, check all of your wiring to ensure there is nothing loose, and try hitting the 'reset' button the Arduino as the compile message changes to uploading, in case your serial adapter isn't resetting the Arduino properly.